# Shouldn't Stack Exchange reputation caps be reduced for upvote?

Tags: discussion

well I'm taking your time now to ask a random question just so I get reputation points allowing to upvote a solution that I just found. I still want to do this in order to show other people having that exact issue what solution worked. I consider this a community benefit already (= contribution to the community).

Does anyone agree that this requirement for reputation points is not helping the case? Instead of flushing in qualitatively low input like this one why not just allow people with an account to upvote (since they're already part of the community. No need to force them into action)?

Also: Why are there no tags for stackexchange itself?

I'd open a change request for Stack Exchange (if I can find a place where to do that ofc :))

Best,
Chexner

Comment: I suggest you move your questions over to the Meta Q/A site pointed out by Guy Clairbois. I understand this defeats the purpose of getting reputation points. But Salesforce StackExchange is not a discussion board; and the fact it is not makes it so much more useful than many other places. With respect to the points you raise, your text is simply off-topic.

Comment: Basically, the restrictions are a matter of trust. There are some people that want to abuse the gamification of reputation for Internet clout, spam their products, etc. By making people actually interact with the community before they have earned trust makes it harder for this to happen. See our [help topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) on the matter. We do want to include everyone that wants to earnestly wants to be here, but not to allow massive vandalism or spam.